# sub or function not defined copy pasting from one file to another

Tags: vba

I have the following code to copy yearly precipitation data from 132 different excel files to one large dataset.  I have precipitation data from multiple different sites which I am placing in different columns hence the different col values.  I also want to match the dates hence the rw value.  However, I am getting that my sub is not defined and I am not sure why.

```
Sub f()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False

  Dim directory As String, fileName As String
  directory = "C:\Working-Directory\Precipdata"
  fileName = Dir(directory & "*.csv")
  Do While fileName <> ""
    Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)
    With (Workbooks(directory & fileName))
      If Range("B2").Value = "GJOA HAVEN A" Then col = "B & rw :D & rw+lngth-27"
      If Range("B2").Value = "TALOYOAK A" Then col = "E & rw :G & rw+lngth-27"
      If Range("B2").Value = "GJOA HAVEN CLIMATE" Then col = "H & rw :J & rw+lngth-27"
      If Range("B2").Value = "HAT ISLAND" Then col = " & rw :M & rw+lngth-27"
      If Range("B2").Value = "BACK RIVER (AUT)" Then col = "N & rw :P & rw+lngth-27"
      yr = Range("B27").Value
      lngth = (Range("B27").End(xlDown).Row)
    End With
    Workbook(Macroforprecip.xlsm).Activate
    rw = Cells.Find("01/01/" & yr).Row
    Workbooks(fileName).Range("P&R&T" & (Range("B27").End(xlDown).Row)).Copy_Workbooks(Macroforprecip.xlsm).Range (col)
    Workbooks(fileName).Close
    fileName = Dir()
  Loop
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Also I really wanted to use the cells function so I could make col a numeric value and just add two but I can't find how to do the equivalent of Range(""A"& i : "G" & i") with it.

OK so I updated it to be slightly more simple.  I am only copying one column at a time and I did change the workbook() function to workbooks()  my new code looks like this.

```
Sub precipitation()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim directory As String, fileName As String
directory = "C:\Working-Directory\Precipdata\"
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.csv")
    Do While fileName <> ""
        sheetName = Left(fileName, Len(fileName) - 4)
        Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)
        Workbooks(fileName).Activate
                If Range("B1").Value = "GJOA HAVEN A" Then
                col = "B"
                End If
                If Range("B1").Value = "TALOYOAK A" Then
                col = "E"
                End If
                If Range("B1").Value = "GJOA HAVEN CLIMATE" Then
                col = "H"
                End If
                If Range("B1").Value = "HAT ISLAND" Then
                col = "K"
                End If
                If Range("B1").Value = "BACK RIVER (AUT)" Then
                    col = "N"
                End If
            yr = Range("B27").Value
            lngth = (Range("B27").End(xlDown).Row)
       Workbooks("Macroforprecip.xlsm").Activate
           Set rw = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(what:=DateValue("01/01/" & yr))
           r = rw.Row

       Workbooks(fileName).Range("P27", "P" & lngth).Copy_Workbooks("Macroforprecip.xlsm").Range (col & r)
       Workbooks(fileName).Close
       fileName = Dir()
    Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

My new error is that I get "Run-time error '438':
Object doesn't support this property or method."

This happens at the Line that actually does the copying over `

```
(Workbooks(fileName).Range("P27", "P" & lngth).Copy_Workbooks("Macroforprecip.xlsm").Range (col & r)`
```

I do not fully understand what this means and even more so I do not understand what to do about it.  Thank you all for the help so far.

Comment: What are you doing that says the sub is not defined?  Be explicit and include the actual error information.

Comment: The error is Compile Error:
Sub or Function not Defined

Comment: Also, I am about 95% sure that `".. & .."` does not do what you are hoping for in a range expression.  It will almost certainly result in an invalid range expression.

Comment: go into your routine in the VBA editior, and click "Compile .." from the **Debug** menu.  It should put the cursor on or highlight the line it is complaining about.  Tell us what line that is.

Comment: Just for any additional information that may be helpful.  I tried to run solely the
(Workbooks(fileName).Range("P27", "P" & lngth).Copy
 part and got the same error

Answer (score 0):

This line fails:

```
Workbook(Macroforprecip.xlsm).Activate
```

because there's no function called `Workbook`.  You probably meant to use the application workbooks collection, like this:

```
Workbooks("Macroforprecip.xlsm").Activate
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a lot of changes because there were a lot of problems. See if this gets you a little closer:

```
Sub f()
  Dim wb As Workbook ' define workbook object
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False

  Dim directory As String, fileName As String
  directory = "C:\Working-Directory\Precipdata\" ' added backslash
  fileName = Dir(directory & "*.csv")
  Do While fileName <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(directory & fileName) ' set a workbook object
    With wb ' use workbook object instead
      If Range("B2").Value = "GJOA HAVEN A" Then col = "B" & rw & ":D" & rw + lngth - 27 ' fixed
      If Range("B2").Value = "TALOYOAK A" Then col = "E" & rw & ":G" & rw + lngth - 27 ' fixed
      If Range("B2").Value = "GJOA HAVEN CLIMATE" Then col = "H" & rw & ":J" & rw + lngth - 27 ' fixed
      'If Range("B2").Value = "HAT ISLAND" Then col = " & rw :M & rw+lngth-27" ' missing column so removed
      If Range("B2").Value = "BACK RIVER (AUT)" Then col = "N" & rw & ":P" & rw + lngth - 27
      yr = Range("B27").Value
      lngth = (Range("B27").End(xlDown).Row)
      .Activate
      'Workbook(Macroforprecip.xlsm).Activate ' moved into the With
      rw = Cells.Find("01/01/" & yr).Row
      wb.Range("P&R&T" & (Range("B27").End(xlDown).Row)).Copy wb.Range(col) ' not sure what you are trying to do here
    End With
    wb.Close
    fileName = Dir()
  Loop
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```